# Is there a way to automatically convert from localized string to double while taking the current locale into account

Tags: ios, swift

In swift, I would like to make conversions from number to string and back again without having to create a new formatter. Without taking the locale into account, I write:

```
valueAsString = String(format: "%.1f", value) // value = 1.3 -> "1.3"

valueAsDouble = Double(valueAsString) // valueAsString = "1.3" -> 1.3
```

Now, I want to do the same thing but with my current locale which happens to have a decimal comma instead of a decimal dot. But I don't want to have to create a formatter. For the conversion to String, I use:

```
localizedValueAsString = String.localizedStringWithFormat("%.1f", value) // value = 1.3 -> "1,3"
```

However, I haven't been able to find an equivalent to the second step. Is there an "inversion" to `String.localizedStringWithFormat`, i.e. something along the lines of `Double.localizedValue(localizedValueAsString) // "1,3" -> 1.3`?

Comment: Why don't you want to create a formatter?

Comment: Who you gonna call? `NumberFormatter`!

Comment: If you don't wanna use `NumberFormatter` then probably you can do this
`Double(valueAsString.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "."))`

Comment: I want to keep it as simple as possible. I'm new to this but I was told that creating NumberFormatters is hard work and should be avoided when possible.

Comment: The whole reason of `NumberFormatter` is to handle these use cases. Whoever said "Is hard work and should be avoided" is trying to prematurely optimize cause "it'll take 5 extra CPU cycles".

Comment: @UmairAamir That won't work. What about grouping separators?